# Script to find the average intensity (grayscale) of .tiff files

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff

I have a bunch of grayscale tiffs, which are either very "black" or very "white". I need to go through them in a loop, and flag them as "white" or not. My idea is to sample some pixels of each image, and average them to get a "white" or "black" value, then compare it to a threshold. But I'm not very familiar with tiffs.

I would prefer to use python, but I'm open to anything, as long as it's simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

There's either the Python Imaging Library (PIL; http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) or PyLibTiff specifically for working with TIFF files (http://code.google.com/p/pylibtiff/).

Both should also be `pip`/`easy_install`able.